# pig is not visible inside hue

Tags: apache-pig, cloudera-cdh, hue

I have a hadoop cluster.

Pig is installed:
[image]

But the pig editor is not visible inside hue (3.7):
[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your hue.ini file

In the interpreters section, as shown below

```
# One entry for each type of snippet.
  [[interpreters]]
```

Add

```
   [[[pig]]]
      name=Pig
      interface=oozie
```

Restart the service and check Hue again.

I am not sure if this will work, but its worth giving a shot ! Hope this helps !

Comment: I have added the lines in in the hue.ini file and restarted the service but it does not change anything. I have no interpreters section in the configuration file. Where should it be located? Under desktop?